# Scanner Class and InputMismatchException

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

```
while (!s.hasNextDouble())
{
System.out.println("not a value" );
    s.nextDouble();

}

sum = min = max = next = s.nextDouble();    

for (loop follows to decide min and max and average)
```

Why do I get a scanner Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException, when i Run this. I looked at the API and i think I am doing it right. If don't put the s.nextDouble() after the System.out then the loop runs fine, but as soon as type s.nextDouble(); the program crashes.

Comment: Perhaps a bit more detail as to what you're trying to do would be helpful?

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure the "basic" tag is for the programming language BASIC.  Thus, I'm removing that tag.  Please correct if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to read a `Double` while you don't have one to read. Try:

```
while (!s.hasNextDouble())
{
    System.out.println("not a value" );
    s.next();
}
min = max = etc = s.nextDouble();
```